# Dataframes vs list of objects

Tags: python, dataframe, oop

When to use list of objects over dataframes in Python?

I have a list of strings which will have multiple attributes like score, word count, some boolean values, etc. I have created a list of objects with these attributes. But I wonder would it be better to simply create a dataframe with each string as a row and add its attributes as columns

```
class MyObject():

    def getString(self):
        return self.str_name

    def getSimilarity(self):
        return self.similarity

    def getSimilarityBand(self):
        return self.similarity_band
```

Which is a better design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very dependent on your context.

If you're building a job which is reading some data, applying transformations on top of that data and then writing it to an output file/bucket then it is common to use dataframes (e.g. pandas if it will fit into memory or pyspark if it needs to be distributed). One reason for this is there are some optimisations that these libraries do under the hood when applying these kinds of transformations which make your jobs more efficient.

On the other hand, if you're building a more complex application with lots of object hierarchies or something that more closely models the real world where you feel well-defined objects will make your code easier to read, then the object approach makes more sense.

In the end, this comes down to style; and in a way functional programming vs object-oriented programming. Python sits in the middle of these worlds so it's natural that there's going to be some conflict. There's no right or wrong way.

Comment: Thanks @Finlay, I am going to stick with dataframes unless the hierarchy gets more complex.